# How to decode the individuals in a genetic algorithm?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

Not sure if I worded that right.

I have a dataset whih i converted into a df which contains my transactions like :

```
bread  egg  milk  newspaper  orange  pineapple  sugar
0      1    1     0          0       0          0      0
1      0    0     1          0       0          0      0
2      0    0     0          0       0          1      0
3      0    0     0          1       0          0      0
4      1    1     0          0       1          0      0
5      0    0     1          0       0          0      1
6      0    1     0          1       0          0      0
```

I have converted this into a list of bits to populate a genetic algorithm:

`[['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1'], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0']]`

This becomes the initial population in my genetic algorithm.

HOWEVER, I dont know how to design a proper fitness function for this data as the bits are not really carrying their original meaning? ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'] for e.g. does not carry its original support value which I want to use in the fitness function.

Any idea how I can do that?

Also, I'm getting a single best individual at the end of my algorithm (designed with help from tutorials). How can I go about obtaining a number of good individuals??

Comment: What is your goal? to train how many ingredients it would take to generate a given bread? or how much bread would be made given the number of ingredients?

Comment: Each row in the df is a transaction; i wanna find frequent itemsets out of them.